# will with statement close the file properly?

Tags: python, file

I am new to python and get confused about the open file operation. Can anyone please help me to understand the concept? Thanks

I am opening a file in the source_file class:

```
class source_file:
    def close_file(self):
        self.source_file.close()

    define use_file(self):
        
        self.source_file = open(self.file_path, "r", encoding='gbk', errors='ignore')
        with self.source_file as lines:
            do_something()
        print(self.source_file)
        self.close_file()
        print(self.source_file)
        self.source_file.close()
        print(self.source_file)
```

when I run this source_file.use_file()

it shows:

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Temp\\law_dev\\source\source_file.txt' mode='r' encoding='gbk'>

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Temp\\law_dev\\source\source_file.txt' mode='r' encoding='gbk'>

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Temp\\law_dev\\source\source_file.txt' mode='r' encoding='gbk'>

I get confused as when I use the 'with' statement, it should close the file. Or when I use the function close_file, it should close the file. Or when I use self.source_file.close(), it should close the file.

But from the print it seems none of them really close the file. I can still see this file handle.
Is it properly closed?

Comment: You are mixing a bunch of syntax. All you need is: `with open(filepath) as file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've bound the file-handle to the class, so it hasn't left scope yet, which is why you can still see it. However, you can check if it's closed using the `closed` attribute on the file handle. As an example:

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def do_thing(self):
        with open(self.path) as fh:
            # This line is unnecessary, but shows what you are doing
            self.fh = fh
            print(f"Is closed in with? {fh.closed}")

        print(f"Is closed? {fh.closed}")


x = X('somefile.txt')

# Run function, context manager closes file handle
x.do_thing()
Is closed in with? False
Is closed? True

# Can still access file-handle since it's been bound to the instance
x.fh
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='somefile.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
x.fh.closed
True
```

Really you can skip the step where you do `self.fh = fh`, just let the context manager do its thing. Furthermore, if all you are doing is hoping the class helps you close the file, then you can reduce it down to just a function:

```py
def do_thing(path):
    with open(path) as fh:
        # do things with fh
        print(f"I can access fh: {not fh.closed}")

    print(f"And now we're done: {fh.closed}")


do_thing('somefile.txt')
I can access fh: True
And now we're done: True
```

Comment: What I am doing is generating a contract automatically. I am planning to use a class with multiple functions. Each function will generate certain conditions. So I put the open file into the self.source_file. So that different functions can use it as a common handle. I am concerned to use a hard-code way to pass the file path. Do you have a better practice?

Comment: I think you'd need to flesh out your example a bit more. With a surface level understanding at best, I'd say that giving the class a file-handle is probably worse if you're going to re-use it for writing.  At that point, I'd do one of two things: Open for appending and re-use a file path that you've given it or give it a buffered io object like a StringIO that you could write your content to. Then, you read the StringIO into your target file at the end